# Draw a contour in emgucv 3.1

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want too draw a contour in EmguCV 3.1.0.2504 but I get error: "OpenCV: i<0 .Children could not be evaluated."

```
IInputArrayOfArrays biggestCnt = GetBiggestCountour(BinaryImage);
Image<Gray, byte> justCountor = new Image<Gray, byte>(384, 284, new Gray(255));
CvInvoke.DrawContours(justCountor, biggestCnt, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
```

[image]

Comment: Typically I see this error when I have a list that can't be evaluated to anything tangible.  What does GetBiggestCountour() do?  Can you post that as well?

Comment: @Woot GetBiggestCountour() returns the biggest contour of image. I showed the output in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the line :

```
CvInvoke.DrawContours(justCountor, biggestCnt, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
```

to

```
 justCountor.Draw(biggestCnt.ToArray(), new Gray(0), 1);
```

and problem solved.

Comment: This seems to be a systemic issue.... there are loads of methods that seem to throw weird errors when inputs match the requirements.